# Web Share API fails on second execution

Tags: javascript, web-share

I implemented the navigator.share() function in my code. It works on the first call, but when I try to call it again through the same event, I get the NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

I found out that this is usually caused by navigator.share() not being directly called by user input, formerly also if called in a fetch callback. However, today it should be allowed as part of a fetch callback. The behaviour is also strange considering that it works on the first try and just fails on consecutive ones.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are not catching the exception the API throws when the user cancels the share. I just tried canceling and then sharing again for a random [article](https://blog.tomayac.com/2021/01/24/ruby-html-footnotes/) on my blog, and it worked. Here is the code I use:

```js
const share = async () => {
  try {
    await navigator.share({
      title: '',
      text: `“${document.title}” by @tomayac:`,
      url: document.querySelector('link[rel=canonical]').href,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err.name, err.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes, it seems like this was the culprit. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This is still an issue on ios16 when trying to share files

Comment: @heroicsatsuma: Do you have a URL I could look at?